# How to exclude specified from all list of Multisite

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I have a question. I would like to know, how can i exclude specified site from a network Multisite?

Here is the code i am using to call out all the links for the sites in my multisite network.

```
<?php $bcount = get_blog_count(); global $wpdb; $blogs = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' and archived = '0' and public='1'")); if(!empty($blogs)) { ?>
<?php foreach($blogs as $blog) {
$details = get_blog_details($blog->blog_id);
if($details != false) {
$addr = $details->siteurl;
$name = $details->blogname;
if(!(($blog->blog_id == 1)&&($show_main != 1))) { ?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $addr; ?>"><?php echo $name;?></a></li>
       <?php } } } ?><?php } ?>
```

I wish to exclude 1 or 2 specified sites in the future.
Thank you!

*is that possible to add a simple code to the existing code in order to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`get_sites()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/) instead of crafting `$wpdb` calls.

Add this code to your theme's `functions.php` file.

```
function wpse365255_print_sites() {
    $args = array(
        'number' => 10000, // if you've got more than 10,000 sites, 
                           //you can increase this
        'public'        => 1,
        'spam'          => 0,
        'deleted'       => 0,
        'archived'      => 0,
        'site__not_in'  => array( 1, 2 ), 
        // this will exclude sites with ID 1 and 2
    );
    $sites = get_sites( $args ); // will return an array of WP_Site objects 
    $list = '';
    foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
        $details = get_blog_details( $site->blog_id );
        if ( ! empty( $details ) ) {
            $list .= '<li>';
            $list .= '<a href="' . $details->siteurl . '">';
            $list .= $details->blogname;
            $list .= '</a>';
            $list .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    if ( ! empty( $list ) ) {
        echo '<ul>' . $list . '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Then, in your `footer.php` file, replace the code you originally posted with this:

```
<?php
    wpse365255_print_sites();
?>
```

It's generally best to not define functions in template files, but instead put them in `functions.php` and call them from the template files, which is what this will do. (Better still to hook them to an action or filter hook, but that's [a lesson for another day](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/).)

### References

- [`get_sites()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/)
- [`WP_Site` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_site/)

Comment: HI Pat J, thank you for the answer! But, I'm actually not good in php. Can i know how can i implement this to the code or how to modify the code with `get_sites()`?

Comment: Where does the code you currently have (ie, in your original question) reside?

Comment: It's in my themes file. All in my footer.php

Comment: Sorry! I'm not good in this, i don't understand how to use your code in my theme.

Comment: I've updated my answer; hopefully it'll clear things up a bit.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried. But It's not working.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or is it just not displaying the data you expect?

Comment: Getting error. Make the div after the code not showing.

Comment: Pat J, I figured it out. It's just a minor mistake on type on your code. `<?php
    wpse365225_print_sites();
?>`. The mistake is at the number there. The code to place in the functions.php is 365255, but the code to place in footer.php you wrote 365225. That's why can't call the function. By the way, thank you for your code! It works perfectly!

Comment: Hey Pat, One more thing. At some situations, I will still need to use my current code on certain portion. Do you have the idea of how to exclude the site by using the code in my question?